# Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates - an unclear allegation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Many posts on $SE$ are related to solving Laplace's equation and I guess I didn't find the right one to answer my question; so, excuse me if it seems obvious, but there is something I don't understand...

It' related to this document: [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ncarruth/APM346_S19/notes/20190702_04.pdf), in which (first page) the author says:

" Recall that Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates is given by
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\rho^2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\phi^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z^2}=0$$
while substituting in the separated $u=P(\rho)\Phi(\phi)Z(z)$ and dividing by $u$ gives the equation
$$\frac{P^"}{P}+\frac{P^{'}}{\rho P}+\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\Phi^"}{\Phi}+\frac{Z^"}{Z}=0$$
from which we see that we must have both $\frac{\Phi^"}{\Phi}$ and $\frac{Z^"}{Z}$ constant "

I just don't understand why the last sentence "from which we see that we must have both $\frac{\Phi^"}{\Phi}$ and $\frac{Z^"}{Z}$ constant" seems to be so obvious to the author.

Could someone elaborate a bit on this and explain more clearly why "we must have"? I guess I'm stuck on something elementary about differential equations, but that's what precisely escapes me...

Comment: That equation is true for all $z$. When you vary $z$ only the part $Z''/Z$ changes.

Comment: Follow the standard separation of variables technique. First, move everything with $z$ to the right hand side, and conclude that the left and right sides are constant. Then you can move things around until $\phi$ is on one side only and the other variables are on the other side.

Comment: okay, I didn't understand; I see what must be done; we finally end up with 3 differential equations, if I'm not mistaken.